# "equal" arrows without transparent ends possible in tikzcd?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

It appears that `tikzcd` puts a transparent, but visible vertical line at both ends of an `\arrow[equal]` like this:

[image]

I find this somewhat irritating and would like to know if it is possible to make `tikzcd` produce proper "equal" arrows, i.e. without vertical ends, like the good old `xy-pic` does:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because `tikz-cd` uses `double` for that, which draws a white line on top. Here is a simple way to fix this, even with a free bonus. ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{double line with arrow/.style args={#1,#2}{decorate,decoration={markings,%
mark=at position 0 with {\coordinate (ta-base-1) at (0,1pt);
\coordinate (ta-base-2) at (0,-1pt);},
mark=at position 1 with {\draw[#1] (ta-base-1) -- (0,1pt);
\draw[#2] (ta-base-2) -- (0,-1pt);
}}}}
\begin{document}
Original:
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
X \ar[equal]{r} & Y \ar[mapsfrom]{r} & Z
\end{tikzcd}
\]

Fixed:
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
X \ar[-,double line with arrow={-,-}]{r} & Y \ar[mapsfrom]{r} & Z
\end{tikzcd}
\]

Bonus:
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
X \ar[-,double line with arrow={latex-,-latex}]{r} & Y \ar[mapsfrom]{r} & Z
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works great! An additional question if you don't mind: is it possible to actually overwrite the old "equal" style with the new "equal" style?

Comment: @M.G. I do not think it is straightforward, at least I did not manage to do this with straightforward ways. And I would not recommend this either since it might backfire in a way that is hard to predict.  However, you could do `\tikzset{Equal/.style={-,double line with arrow={-,-}}}` and then work with `Equal` instead of `equal`.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! Indeed `Equal` does the job just as well, thanks for the excellent suggestion.