# Circle label of xymatrix

Tags: labels, xy-pic, xymatrix

Related from my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/601125/dotted-arrow-with-a-circle-in-it-and-a-vertical-equal-sign) where I must put the `|` to have the label into the arrow considering `\ar@{.>}[d]^*+<8pt>[o][F]{\ell}`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=40pt{ \mathbb{Z}/m \ar@{.>}[d]^*+<8pt>[o][F]{\ell}
\\ \mathbb{Z}/n
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have found himself the answer.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=30pt{ \mathbb{Z}/m \ar@{.>}[d]|*+<7pt>[o][F]{\ell}
\\ \mathbb{Z}/n}
\end{document}
```

[image]